# Fluctuations in the cosmological equation of state during the radiation dominated era

Tags: cosmology

The [radiation dominated era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)#Radiation-dominated_era) is described as a universe full of photons and ultra-relativistic particles with little slow moving matter. Ideally it has *w* = P/ρ = 1/3.

But didn't the actual value of *w* move down *and up* over this era?
My reasoning is as follows: When the temperature gets within an order of magnitude of a particle's mass said particles start moving significantly slower than light and *w* will drop below 1/3. However, when it cools off further [almost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_asymmetry) all of those particles annihilate and *w* rises up again.

*This is my best understanding of how w changes:*

At the end of inflation (during which *w* ~ -1) we get [reheating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#Reheating). The temperature, T, is in the range of 10^22 eV. No elementary particles 173 GeV < m <~ 10^25 eV are [known to exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_(particle_physics)) (unless dark matter WIMPS are in this mass range). All the particle we know about have much less rest mass than T, so they are ultra-relativistic and *w* is very close to 1/3.

When T drops to ~173 GeV top quarks are no longer ultra-relativistic and *w* drops. Other particles are soon to follow. As the temperature drops quarks become less and less free.

When T drops below ~100 MeV quarks of any kind get rare. This is because the lightest isolatable particle with quarks is the [pion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) at 135 and 140 MeV. No free quarks are known to exist, so the small mass of up and down quarks is irrelevant. Muons (m = 105MeV) also get rare around this point. Thus *w* increases to nearly 1/3.

When T nears ~500 keV electrons and positrons are no longer ultra-relativistic and *w* drops again. But when T gets lower they annihilate and *w* rises.

When T ~ 3eV ~ 30000K, the tiny amount of matter left over becomes dominant and *w* trends to zero (which just happens to be at 3eV). Note that this is a while before recombination occurs (T 0.3eV ~ 3000K). Even without baryon and WIMP asymmetry, neutrino masses are ~eV range (neutrinos interact too weakly to annihilate at the low densities in this era) so they would drive down *w* to zero around this time. The radiation era is over and it will be a long time before dark energy starts to matter.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: As far as I know there is no "general w". Each particle type has its own $w$. So I dont think you can talk about for $w$ going up and down. Of course it decreases once a particle becomes non-relativistic but other then that it does not change

Comment: @Layla: I mean the average *w* of all matter and energy at a given time.

Comment: I see your point. I have some ideas but I am not sure they are true or not so Idk